# match quantity with the closest discount amount

Tags: php

**I've got a shopping cart that I am developing and need to figure out a way to match the discount rates to the quantity.**

***Discount Rates apply at***

- 1 item
- 2 items (5 percent discount)
- 5 items (10 percent discount)
- 10 items (20 percent discount)

*So 2-4 items would get the 2 item discount, 5-9 items would get the 5 item discount.  10+ items would get the 10 item discount.*

**Lets say the customer buys 7 items.  The code would need to apply the discount rate for 5 items.**

---

I thought about a for loop where it auto increments the value `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` however; I'm not sure how to tie the discount rates into that and stop the variable at the correct discount rate.

---

I also saw a code like this.. `(quantity * unitcost) - (int (quantity / 2) * (unitcost / 2))` which that only applies a specific discount for every second item so that wouldnt work.

---

I searched google for this but kept seeing example of how to do quantity discounts in specific shopping carts.

```
$quantity = quantity of items in cart
```

If there is a way to set up discounts as an array and match the closest that way that would be best scenerio unless someone knows a better way.

```
$discount = array();
$Discount[1] = 0 percent
$Discount[2] = 5 percent
$Discount[5] = 10 percent
$Discount[10] = 20 percent
```

I'm using these discounts as an example.  Discounts are actually going to be pulled in from the product database because different items can have different discount rates.

***I wish I could show a code that is partially working but I'm at a loss with this one.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.***

Comment: Make a map, if that's the right terminology (I'm most familiar with Java), (might be called a dict) of your marginal rate changes, then iterate through the map until the number exceeds the current key. Then return the corresponding value.

Comment: I thought about that....but implementing that is a different scenerio...haha .  And I'm not sure if thats the best method overall.  Which is why I'm asking for help.  I want this to use a good method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple use of if and elseif would make it easy.

```
if ($quantity >= 10) {
    $discount = 20;
} elseif ($quantity >= 5) {
    $discount = 10;
} elseif ($quantity >= 2) {
    $discount = 5;
} else {$discount = 0;}
```

The same logic could be handled with dynamic discounts and quantities retrieved from a database.

And to do it based on your update using values from your database:

```
$input = array("1"=>"0","2"=>"5","5"=>"10","10"=>"20");
$reversed = array_reverse($input,true);

foreach ($reversed as $qtydiscount => $discount) {

    if ($quantity >= $qtydiscount) {
        break;
    }
}

echo $discount;
```

Comment: I should go ahead and get out of coding right now.  haha.  How in the world did I not think to do this.....

Comment: Sometimes it is easy to miss the forest because of all of the trees :)

Comment: I'm getting this result from database for `quantity => discount` ...... `1=>0,2=>5,5=>10,10=>20`   I'm use to splitting that out via an explode and setting up an array.  But there may be a better way,  How would I use that data to format your code?  Thats where I'm stuck at.

Comment: This is the sample code I started with... `$input = array("1"=>"0","2"=>"5","5"=>"10","10"=>"20");
$reversed = array_reverse($input,true);`

Comment: Updated my answer based on your additional input. If it works please accept the answer :)

Comment: How does that work?  I accepted answer, but really curious how it returns the discount when discount isnt defined or returned inside the foreach loop

Comment: I see where you updated your code for the foreach loop.  It worked.  Thats why i accepted.  But I'm curious HOW it worked.  I don't get how it returns the $discount outside the array.  And how it returns the correct one.  You don't have to answer that I guess but I was hoping to understand it a little more.

Comment: by the way, I am from North Carolina as well :)

Comment: Discount is set on every iteration of the foreach. If something matches the if the foreach is ended and whatever discount was last set to is what you get and use. Since your reversed array has the quantity minimum as 1 you should at least always get a value of zero for discount. Variable scope does not come into play in this case.